# Use dynamic path based on environment in Angular .scss file

Tags: css, angular, angular12

I have one angular component which is using some external styles sheet, along with component's own style sheet. I am importing external css file in component's .scss file at top like shown below (highlighted). This is working fine and css is getting applied to component's elements. However this style sheet is environment specific.
For example:

- In local it is http://localhost:8080/styles.css
- On Dev it should be @import http://dev-server/styles.css
- On Test environment it should be @import http://test-server/styles.css

I am not sure how can I pass this path dynamically based on environment. Please suggest.

[image: component .scss file]

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use environment files (`.ts`) into style files (`.scss`).

**However**, what you can do is the same thing the environment is doing, to replace your files at build time.

First, create those files :

```
imports.local.scss
imports.dev.scss
imports.tests.scss
```

And fill them with the corresponding imports.

Then, in your `angular.json`, you can use those properties :

```json
{
  ...,
  "projects": {
    "yourProject": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "configurations": {
            "yourEnvironmentNameLikeProductionOrTestOrDev": {
              ...
              "fileReplacements": [
                ...
                {
                  "replace": "src/styles/imports.local.scss",
                  "with": "src/styles/imports.[your environment name].scss"
                }
              ]
              ...
            },
```

Comment: This way I need to create 3 .scss files for that component and pick the right one based on environment during build.. right?.. that seems interesting

Comment: @Gurmeet that's it, it's exactly how the `environment` files work too. From what I see, this is the only solution available to you !

Comment: Thanks for this.. it will sort out my problem I believe.