# Error: Expected "styleUrls" to be an array of String

Tags: angular, webpack, tsconfig, angular-decorator

Getting this error when I am using dynamic styleUrls.

```
var dynamic = environment.booleanCondition ? '-new' : '';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-some-thing',
  templateUrl: './some-thing.component.html',
  styleUrls: [require(`./some-thing${dynamic}.component.scss`).default]
})
```

I am facing this issue with ng serve

> Error: Expected "styleUrls" to be an array of String

After recompiles, error vanishes and application works fine but it throws different error on terminal.

> error TS2591: Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.

But even after installing `@types/node` and adding `node`, it still don't resolves my previous issue of "styleUrls" to be an array of String.
I have seen this issue posted many times before but none of fixes seems to work for me.

Comment: I would expect, that you would run into runtime errors with something like this. Since the @Component Anotations are (I think) evaluated on compile time if you however change it during runtime this either doesn't change a thing or throws errors. If you want your styling to fundamentally change depending on this condition you can use [ngClass] on a surounding container or something

Comment: I have two very different and complex Stylesheets, which I have to render as per different condition. Updating complete template and styles, should be my last choice I hope.

Comment: You can try adding a toString() e.g. styleUrls: [require(`./some-thing${dynamic}.component.scss`).default.toString()]

Comment: I don’t expect this approach to work. Is the condition build time or runtime?

Comment: Condition is Runtime, do you think this could be the issue ? @MikeOne

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer:

The OP updated the question that the variable from `environment.ts` file determines which scss file to use. In that case, there are few ways to pick up the file to use:

Option 1:

Copy targeted file to a main file via package.json command (independent of `environment.ts`)

Make the main scss file empty, so that desired css can be copied into it.
In package.json, create script like following:

```
copy-old-scss: 'cp .src/{path-to-your-old-scss-file}/old-file.scss ./src/{path-to-main-scss-file}/something.component.scss'
copy-new-scss: 'cp .src/{path-to-your-new-scss-file}/old-file.scss ./src/{path-to-main-scss-file}/something.component.scss'
```

Execute these script before running your build command pipeline per env:

```
'dev':
   - step:
     script:
       - npm install --quiet
       - npm copy-old-scss
       - npm run build

'prod':
   - step:
     script:
       - npm install --quiet
       - npm copy-new-scss
       - npm run build
```

Option 2:

Use `angular.json` fileReplacements feature as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72029022/use-dynamic-path-based-on-environment-in-angular-scss-file)

angular.json:

```
    "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              ...
              ...
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                },
                {
                  "replace": "src/.../something.component.scss",
                  "with": "src/.../something-new.component.scss"
                }
              ],
```

Original answer:

Instead of doing such non-standard Angular thing, why don't you take a more conventional approach, where you control all of css from one file. If I had to the option, I would do it this way.

1. Modify the flag to boolean, `let useNewCss = booleanCondition;`
2. Combine both scss file into one, but within the file maintain specific section for old css and new css:

something.component.scss:

```
.old-css {
   // all css from my old file goes here
}

.new-css {
  // all css from my new file goes here 
}
```

3. Use `ngClass` to wrap the whole html code within desired css class

something.component.html:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'old-css': !useNewCss, 'new-css': useNewCss }">
  <!-- All html code goes here -->
  ...
  ...
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: I have two very different and complex Stylesheets, merging one would not be possible now it seems, as short on time. Condition is runtime, so it is failing on build I think. On local @Raffeal suggestion works.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can explain in the question what condition is deciding which file to use. Is it a url param, a value from server, something else?

Comment: I am using environment based value now. Updated in question. @Nehal

Comment: I am still not clear on your specific requirement, but based on your updated question, I have provided few options per my understanding.